# In Django Rest Framework, how do I serialize values to an array of values rather than an array of objects?

Tags: django, json, django-models, django-rest-framework

In Django Rest Framework, how do I serialize values to an array of values rather than an array of objects? Here is a sample of my serializer code:

```
class NodeTagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = NodeTag
        fields = (
            'name',
        )


class NodeTreeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = NodeTagSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = NodeTree
        fields = (
            'tags',
        )
```

This is returning:

```
"tags": [
    {"name": "Tag1"},
    {"name": "Tag2"}
]
```

But I want:

```
"tags": [
    "Tag1",
    "Tag2"
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the to_native() method to return the tag name directly (untested):

```
class NodeTagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_native(self, obj):
        return obj.name
```

Comment: @user9: care to elaborate? Perhaps in a different question if it's too long?

Answer (score 8):

The answer to this changed in v3. The new way to do it is:

```
class NodeTagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  def to_representation(self, obj):
      return obj.name
```